# Script for calling jar file, which is updated with new name

Tags: linux, shell-script, ubuntu

I have created this script

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar /opt/elcor/web/elcor-web-0.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

and everytime I upload a new version in `/opt/elcor/web/` I have to manually modify the script, because every new version of the file has a different release number: `elcor-web-0.1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar`, etc, etc...
and I want to know if there is a way to do it automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three solutions:

1. Always use only one name.  An update would overwrite the old name.  The script would only refer to that name and would not need updating.
2. Always remove old `jar` files before updating, and use

   ```
   java -jar /opt/elcor/web/elcor-web-*.jar
   ```

   in your script.  This assumes that the pattern does not expand to anything other than one single `jar` file.
3. Maintain a symbolic link to the latest `jar` file.

   ```
   ln -s /opt/elcor/web/elcor-web-0.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /opt/elcor/web/elcor-web-latest.jar
   ```

   Then use the symbolic link in the script:

   ```
   java -jar /opt/elcor/web/elcor-web-latest.jar
   ```

   This requires you to update the symbolic link when downloading a new `jar` file (this could be part of the update procedure), but the script would not need to change.